# datetimepicker is not displaying calendar using NgRoute of AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm having some problems when I tried to open a calendar using jquery ui thru NgRoute Angularjs. I've tried removing ng-view tag and it works fine. i need it working with NgRoute.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">

<head lang="en">
  <title>AngularJS Routing</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>

  <li> <a href="#/datePicker"> Date Picker</a> </li>

  <div ng-app="mainApp">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.jsp

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/datePicker', {
            templateUrl: 'DatePicker.html',
            controller: 'DemoCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/index'
        });
});

mainApp.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

      //$('#datepicker1').datepicker();

}]);

})();
```

DatePicker.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
         });
    </script>
  </head>

<body>

  <form>
    <p>Fecha: <input id="datepicker1" type="text" ></p>
    <a href="#/index"> Main menu</a>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wk4zZo0WfoypMmaMgv4j

I will appreciate any help on this issue.

Thank you so much,
Ariel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in DatePicker.html you dont need all tags again only the ones that will go inside ng-view:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
     });
</script>

<form>
   <p>Fecha: <input id="datepicker1" type="text" ></p>
   <a href="#/index"> Main menu</a>
</form>
```

And this will go inside index.html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

I dont know if it will sove your problem, but it is the correct thing to do...

Comment: I'll leave this plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/aVdvJoFIIhtQTknuoiRs?p=preview :-)